# Calculating determinant of a matrix product

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $M =\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & ...& 0 \\
        ... & ... & ... & ...\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        x_1  & x_2 &... & x_n
        \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} &E & \\ x_1 & ... & x_n\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{(n+1) \times n}$

where $E \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}  $ is the identity matrix.

Is there any easy way to show that $\det(M^T M) = 1 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 + ... + x_n^2 ?  $

It should be obvious that $M^TM = E + K$, where $K$ is a symmetric matrix with $k_{ij} = x_ix_j$ for $1 \le i,j \le n $

Usually I would apply $\det (AB) = \det(A) \det(B) $, but that doesn't work 
because $M \in \mathbb R^{(n+1) \times n}$.

Anyone got a hint?

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed
$$M^TM = E + K,$$
where $(K)_{ij}=k_{ij} = x_ix_j$, that is ${\rm rank}(K)=1$.

In this case, there is a general fact, that if ${\rm rank}(A)=1$, then
$$\det(E+A) = 1+{\rm tr}(A).$$
It can be proved easily by considering the normal Jordan form of a matrix $A$. Since the rank of $A$ is 1, then the Jordan form of a $A$ has simple form.

By this it follows
$${\rm det}(M^TM) = 1 + {\rm tr}(K) = 1+x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2.$$

Comment: Could you explain why is $rank(K) = 1$ ?

Comment: Because if $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)$, then $K = x^Tx$, and ${\rm rank}(x)={\rm rank}(x^T)=1$, and $0<{\rm rank}(K)\le {\rm rank}(x){\rm rank}(x^T)=1$

Comment: @Mher The general fact follows from the [Sylvester's determinant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem)) with an easy proof without Jordan decompositions.